# multiple apps getting installed in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I created an app that includes more than one layout. And I made a java file for each of those layout. When I run the application in emulator an app for each layout are individually being created. But I could navigate well as I have instructed in the code.

What could be the reason for this? How to let them come under one single application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` set for all your activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Remove this line for every activity you do *not* want to show up in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

change  to

if that does not work we'll need to see the manifest... it could also be that you have created these activities in different packages.